# Andorid Facebook Login Error After Clicking Login Button

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an issue which the Facebook login button click on Android. After I click the button, it shows ERROR Page with the message "Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again."

Here is the code:

```
public class FacebookLoginFragment extends Fragment  {
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
public FacebookLoginFragment(){
    super();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook_login_fragment, container, false);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            System.out.println("Success");
            System.out.println(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            System.out.println("canceled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

In case you are wondering this is on com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0.

Comment: Right now, I have the same issue. A couple of weeks ago, my login implementation (looks pretty much like yours) works fine. Maybe it is a temporary Facebook issue?

Comment: Yeah this just happened yesterday suddenly, not sure why, it was working fine 2 days ago.@funcoder

Comment: Well, I know it is a bit late, but I fixed the issue in the meanwhile. In general, you have to enter the corresponding key hash of your Android debug certificate in the Facebook developer console (Settings -> Basic -> Key Hash). During development, I made a clean build. This has the effect, that (most probably) the debug certificate is new generated and has a new hash. I updated the Hash of my debug certificate in the facebook console and everything works fine now. I do not know, why facebook is not capable to display a clear error message... @Hong Wei Wang

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for facebook login. It's works for me.

```html
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

List < String > permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
 "user_birthday", "public_profile", "AccessToken");
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {@Override
 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

  System.out.println("onSuccess");

  String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken()
   .getToken();
  Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
  loginResult.getAccessToken(),
  new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {@Override
   public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
   GraphResponse response) {

    Log.i("LoginActivity",
    response.toString());
    try {
     String id = object.getString("id");
     try {
      URL profile_pic = new URL(
       "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large");
      Log.i("profile_pic",
      profile_pic + "");

     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     String name = object.getString("name");
     String email = object.getString("email");
     String gender = object.getString("gender");
     String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("fields",
   "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
  request.setParameters(parameters);
  request.executeAsync();
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancel() {
  System.out.println("onCancel");
 }

 @Override
 public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
  System.out.println("onError");
  Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
 }
});
```

```html
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
 callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Pretty much have the same code.